# Opposite of timeago.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timeago

I found a nifty little time-to-text jQuery plugin called [timeago.js](http://timeago.yarp.com/) (think Twitter timestamps.) 
It's [not a complex plugin](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/jquery.timeago.js), but it saves good dev time, and I especially like that it auto-updates.

Only problem is, I need this functionality to work for **dates in the future**, not just the past. (i.e. "timeuntil.js"?)

Has anyone come across a plugin (or they're own solution) that emulates the functionality described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um... Just change "ago" to "from now" or whatever and flip the order of the dates

[edit] Or just bother to *read* the documentation a little bit :)

```
jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try out [**momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/), it's far better than any other js date libraries out there

Comment: Definitely an excellent solution... a bit heavy though for my needs. Thanks!